# why my Multi threaded parallel sum function's vector is limited depended to the number of threads?

Tags: c++, recursion, parallel-processing, sum, threadpool

I have written a recursive sum parallel function that gets a vector of numbers, a threadpool and the vector size, and it should return the sum of the vector, but when i want to use, like the example below, a 20 cells sized vector, i must use atleast 8 threads or else, the program will be stuck and won't complete (and won't throw an error).

this is the threadpool code i am using:

```
#ifndef THREAD_POOL_H
#define THREAD_POOL_H

#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>
#include <functional>
#include <stdexcept>

class ThreadPool {
public:
    ThreadPool(size_t);
    template<class F, class... Args>
    auto enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args) 
        -> std::future<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type>;
    ~ThreadPool();
private:
    // need to keep track of threads so we can join them
    std::vector< std::thread > workers;
    // the task queue
    std::queue< std::function<void()> > tasks;

    // synchronization
    std::mutex queue_mutex;
    std::condition_variable condition;
    bool stop;
};

// the constructor just launches some amount of workers
inline ThreadPool::ThreadPool(size_t threads)
    :   stop(false)
{
    for(size_t i = 0;i<threads;++i)
        workers.emplace_back(
            [this]
            {
                for(;;)
                {
                    std::function<void()> task;

                    {
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->queue_mutex);
                        this->condition.wait(lock,
                            [this]{ return this->stop || !this->tasks.empty(); });
                        if(this->stop && this->tasks.empty())
                            return;
                        task = std::move(this->tasks.front());
                        this->tasks.pop();
                    }

                    task();
                }
            }
        );
}

// add new work item to the pool
template<class F, class... Args>
auto ThreadPool::enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args) 
    -> std::future<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type>
{
    using return_type = typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type;

    auto task = std::make_shared< std::packaged_task<return_type()> >(
            std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
        );

    std::future<return_type> res = task->get_future();
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);

        // don't allow enqueueing after stopping the pool
        if(stop)
            throw std::runtime_error("enqueue on stopped ThreadPool");

        tasks.emplace([task](){ (*task)(); });
    }
    condition.notify_one();
    return res;
}

// the destructor joins all threads
inline ThreadPool::~ThreadPool()
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);
        stop = true;
    }
    condition.notify_all();
    for(std::thread &worker: workers)
        worker.join();
}

#endif
```

this is my sum parallel function:

```
int Sum_Parallelled(int *begin, ThreadPool *threadPool,int size) {
    if (size == 1) {
        return *begin;
    } else {
        auto res = threadPool->enqueue(Sum_Parallelled, (begin), threadPool, size / 2);
        if (size % 2 == 0) {
            return Sum_Parallelled(begin + (size / 2), threadPool, size / 2) + res.get();
        } else {
            return Sum_Parallelled(begin + (size / 2), threadPool, size / 2 + 1) + res.get();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the main function code:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){ // creating a vector with x cells.
        vec.push_back(i);
    }
    ThreadPool threadPool(8); // creating a threadpool with y threads.
    int size = vec.size();
    int sum = threadPool.enqueue(Sum_Parallelled,vec.data(),&threadPool,size).get();
    std::cout << "The sum in the parallel sum: " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve] as part of your question. I see several things that look questionable, but it's impossible to tell without further parts of your code.

Comment: i have tried to debug it but it just stops working and i dont know why, thats why i gave the example

Comment: I believe you, but that's not the point. Everyone here should be able to take your code, throw it into a single file and compile it. No multiple files, no modifications to the code, no manual input (not a problem here) -- the code should be usable as is to serve as example for your question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to sum up your twenty numbers, you first start a task (in a thread) that sums up the twenty numbers recursively. This task starts two tasks that sum up one half of the twenty numbers each. It then sits there, waiting for the two tasks to finish and finally returns the result. It blocks one of the threads from the pool the whole time though. If you write down when each thread picks up a task and finishes one, you will see that with twenty numbers, you need more parallel tasks than you have threads, hence the hanging program.

Your problem was caused by the use of recursion, which is the wrong tool for the job. Consider a tree that puts each task in relation to a parent task. At the leaves, you have tasks that get a range of just one number, at the root you have the task with twenty numbers. Now, each task that has children is blocked until both children are finished. With a fixed threadpool size, you can only process a certain tree size, because the tree size determines the distance root to leaf and thus the number of threads blocked waiting for child tasks. If the height is too large, the threads are blocked waiting for child tasks that are never executed, because there are no free threads.

Comment: is there any way i can use for example - 4 threads on a vector with a size of for example - 8092 cells?

Comment: Of course, you assign each of the four threads one quarter of the range.

Comment: Suggestion for a solution: Pack the required calculations into a type of datastructue (which just contains which range of elements to merge, together with an output pointer). Then always push those onto a global, threadsafe queue and use your threadpool to work on that queue with all threads.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Sum_Parallelled` enqueues a new sub-task for the first half of its range *and blocks until that task is complete*.

So, if the number of outstanding tasks can ever exceed the number of threads, you will deadlock.

We can easily write out the number of tasks that will be created for a given input:

```
sp(20) -> sp(10) + sp(10)
sp(10) -> (sp(5) + sp(5))
sp(5)  -> (sp(2) + sp(3))
```

etc.

So calling your function with size=20 will:

1. create two tasks with size=10 *and block the current thread until they both return*.

   State: one thread is blocked waiting, with two tasks on the queue.
2. each size=10 task will create two size=5 tasks *and block until they both return*.

   State: three threads blocked waiting, with four tasks on the queue.
3. each size=5 task will create one size=2 task and one size=3 task *and block until they both return*.

   State: seven threads blocked waiting, with eight tasks on the queue.

so clearly the next level will have have all the available threads waiting for tasks that can never execute.

This is also obviously inefficient: even if we have enough threads, they're mostly just blocked waiting for other threads instead of doing anything useful.

Fortunately, it's easy to come up with better ways of organizing this. For example:

1. Just create one task per thread, each summing 1/nthreads of the vector, and then sum the results when they're all done.

   Downsides: it shifts (some of) the logic up a level, and if the input vector is *very* large, the single-threaded final accumulation could be a bottleneck

   Upsides: unless vector is very large indeed, this simple scheme will perform much better.
2. Create two sub-tasks at each level, as you do now, but instead of waiting for their results, just return a pair of futures.

Comment: /thanks!, do you recommend any of your ways? right now i have a function that all it does is for loop that sums up a vector, but i want to make that function more effective and run in less time. and i never worked with futures before, is it complicated?

Comment: Your threadpool already uses futures, so you have a working example of how to do it. TBH the threshold for multi-threaded vector summation to be faster than single-threaded is pretty high - you can sum a lot of cache-friendly integers in the time it takes to start a thread, or switch context.